# Navigate to next conflict with vimdiff

Tags: vim, vi, merge-conflict-resolution, vimdiff

In vimdiff you can use `[c` and `]c` to go to the previous or next change, but when doing three-way merging many of those changes are not conflicts. Is there a command to go to the next *conflict*, not the next change as in e.g. Kaleidoscope?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You mean conflict markers such as `<<<<<<<`, `=======`, and `>>>>>>>` on merges to indicate that the automatic resolution failed?!

You can use my [ConflictMotions plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3991) for that; it provides `]x` and `[x` mappings, `]=` for navigation within a conflict, and even corresponding text objects `ax` and `a=`.

Comment: Although maybe not as complete as Ingo's ConflictMotions plugin. Tim Pope's unimpaired.vim provides some conflict motions as well. `[n` and `]n` jump to the previous and next conflict markers. Unimpaired.vim provides many other helpful mappings that are well worth a look in my opintion. https://github.com/tpope/vim-unimpaired

Comment: So the answer is without plugins there is no standard solution for this?

Comment: @erikb85: Without plugins, you have to do searches like `/^<<<<<<<`.

Comment: The plugins seem like a great idea. Without those, I usually use a search like `/<<<<<<<\|=======\|>>>>>>>` and then I can use `n` and `p` to skip around between the markers. Not quite as nice as those plugins, clearly, but it works.